# Target class [App\HTTP\Controllers\PropertyController] does not exist

Tags: php, nginx, laravel-10

I know this question has been asked a dozen times and has a dozen answers.  But none have helped me.

I just deployed a new Laravel 10 App to AWS running an Ubuntu Server with the latest stable release.

PHP 8.1

```
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.1.2, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.1.2-1ubuntu2.11, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

NGINX
`nginx version: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)`

web.php

```
use App\HTTP\Controllers\PropertyController;

# Property Functions
Route::get('/claim_property/{name?}', [PropertyController::class, 'index'])
    ->name('claim_property');
Route::post('/claim_property', [PropertyController::class, 'save'])
    ->name('claim_property_store');
```

File Structure:
[image]

NGINX Config:
[image]

I have run:

```
composer dump-autoload
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan route:cache
```

https://flareapp.io/share/B5ZGqB2m#debug

Can anyone help me?  What am I doing wrong?
It works locally under Sail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In *web.php* change `use App\HTTP\Controllers\PropertyController;` with `use App\Http\Controllers\PropertyController;`

Then, if necessary, repeat:

```
composer dump-autoload
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan route:cache
```

Comment: That was the solution.  Thank you so very much.